# Compiling a java package with Libraries in windows CMD

Tags: java, compilation, twitter4j

I have a Java package containing one class I'm trying to compile in windows CMD.

Here's the folder structure:

[image: Folder structure]

`.\src\` contains the packages. I'm trying to compile the class inside the AggregationEngine package. The class is called `testClass.java` and it uses the `twitter4j` library. The jar files of the `twitter4j` library are included in the `.\src\lib\` directory as `twitter4j-core-2.2.4.jar`

I tried the following:

```
javac -classpath "..\lib\twitter4j-core-2.2.4.jar" -sourcepath C:\x\x\x\src\AggregationEngine\ AggregationEngine\TwitterCrawler.java

java AggregationEngine.testClass "test String"

pause
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I have a basic understanding of the above. I'm not even sure if the above is the correct way to do it.

**Note:** I don't want to go into the Environment variable definition method, because I'm gonna do the same on a different OS. Oh and I might also include multiple `.jar` files as well.

-- Edit --
Output: when running the app. `java AggregationEngine.TwitterCrawler`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j/TwitterException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: twitter4j.TwitterException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Any advice?

Comment: What exactly means "doesn't seem to work"? Do you get a compiler error? Nothing? Do demons start flying out of your nose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is simply that the twitter4j JAR is missing when you try to execute your program. The compiler only uses classpath entries to verify the correctness of the code, it does not include them into its output.

This should work:

```
java -classpath .;..\lib\twitter4j-core-2.2.4.jar AggregationEngine.testClass "test String"
```

Comment: Now I get the following: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: AggregationEngine/TwitterCrawler
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AggregationEngine.TwitterCrawler
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
     Program will exit.`  Any ideas?

Comment: @Link: is "testClass" a standing for TwitterCrawler? Or do both exist? Have you compiled both, i.e. is there a .class file for each? It may be all you have to do is to add the current directory to the classpath - I'll change the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Could you use ant ? it's probably the easiest way of doing it :)

http://ant.apache.org/

Comment: I prefer not to use 3rd party solutions unless I don't find an answer and it's very necessary.

Answer (score 0):

...or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), including Twitter4j in your Maven project is explained in http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html#maven

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too old but for those like me - the problem of ClassNotFound for TwitterException was solved by including log4j, slf4j and commons-logging jars in the project since twitter4j core uses them.